# OutputHTML from search pushing content down instead of on-top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a search bar in a page where a javascript file outputs a custom div class like:

`<div class="course-card"><h5>${match.coursename}</h5></div>`

So whenever a user starts typing in the search bar, there is an autocomplete feature (by using regex to match from a json file). I used the code from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iysNUrI3lw).

The problem is, I have a new row of cards right under the search form so the generated div class (the autocomplete suggestions) pushes the cards down instead of being created on top:

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

But instead, the result is pushing all the content below it down.

I've tried using

```
.course-cards, .content-cards {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    left 0px;
}
```

On the div of the matched `course-cards` and the content below it, and changing the `z-index` but it messes up the course-cards that is generated from the search bar.
[image]

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: if you try to select a css class name, you have to adress it with a dot like: .course-cards, and  if  id, than with #

Comment: fixed, they're in my source code, forgot to put them when I was writing the question

Comment: question, what is the 'preferred' approach? 1. Gently pushing the code down with css animations or 2. Placing the suggestions on top of the below content (as is desired here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
.content-container {
z-index: 1;
}

#match-list {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I put one div around the content cards and one around the list of result cards with the above css

Comment: mm..... but this solution is not a good fit for me do you know any more solutions ? :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `.course-cards` from this css property they don't need to be `position: absolute`.
2. Wrap search `input` and `.course-cards` with one parent div and set `position: relative;` to this parent.
3. Remove `top: 0px;` and write `bottom: 0;` instead.

After that seach-results block will cling on bottom of search-bar, and will be over page content under it.